# Does legacy salt string support in Moodle 1.9.7 include support for non-salted passwords?

Tags: php, encryption, moodle

We have an active Moodle installation recently updated to 1.9.7. This site has never used password salts before. I want to enable password salts on the system, as Moodle recommends now for 1.9.7, but **I am not sure if the legacy salt support setting includes support for non-salted passwords**.

Reviewing [the password sale documentation](http://docs.moodle.org/en/report/security/report_security_check_passwordsaltmain) on Moodle.org doesn't make it clear (to me) if the legacy salt support also includes support for no salt at all. My question is, will a zero length string salt for my legacy salt setting in config.php mean support for non-salted passwords?

E.g., can I add this in my config.php file:

```
$CFG->passwordsaltalt1 = '';
$CFG->passwordsaltmain = 'my new salt which is super secure';
```

and have current account holders still log in if their password isn't salted? I can't tell if this is right from their documentation and I'm wondering if anyone has successfully done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed this with testing: Enabling a password salt does not affect unsalted logins, so you don't need to add a legacy entry for non-salted passwords.